# couchDB: storing MB per document

Tags: erlang, couchdb

I am analyzing couchDB at the moment.  Is it possible to storage MB worth of data **per document**?  E.g. a JPEG image.

I understand I would need to encode (base64 or something) the said data in order to fit the JSON container.

Practical advice sought please.

Comment: Why not store them as attachments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As zed said in his comment the best way to do this is using attachments. The Wiki has a section on this: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Attachments

the basic idea is like so:

```
{
  "_id":"attachment_doc",
  "_attachments":
  {
    "foo.txt":
    {
      "content_type":"text\/plain",
      "data": "VGhpcyBpcyBhIGJhc2U2NCBlbmNvZGVkIHRleHQ="
    }
  }
}
```

You are correct that you should Base64 encode the attachments contents. You can have multiple attachments per document.

**NOTE** from the wiki: *Please note that any base64 data you send has to be on a single line of characters, so pre-process your data to remove any carriage returns and newlines.*

Comment: I realize this thanks: I am more concerned about the *size* per document, hence the "practical advice" note.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that megabytes of size won't have a detrimental effect on the database. It shouldn't affect query times or access times if that's what you were worried about. The only caveat about attachments is that you can't map/reduce over their contents so if you need to deep query them that might be an issue.

Comment: Note that you don't have to upload your attachments in Base64. You can create the document, and then separately add the attachment in a raw put request. See http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP%5FDocument%5FAPI#Standalone_Attachments for details.

Comment: @brian: you should have put it in an answer: I am very good on up-votes.

Comment: I'm kinda late back here, but of course I meant real and not inline attachments, exactly what Brian is talking about. I never really understood the point of inline attachments; reason might be I'm still living somewhere between web 1.1 and web 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried big *documents* but I'm using documents with big *attachments* (JPEGs > 10 Mpix) and that works well.

The main issue is that which such huge database sizes replication tend to break in new and interesting ways every week.